# How to take the values from one class in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, geosparql

From my Consept class I want to print the values it has. For example:
The Consept has:
M0000111
M1232132
M0091911
M12321321
M12321213
M00032422

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?values
 WHERE {
  ?values rdf:type owl:Consept.
}
```

My attempt code shows nothing. I don't know, where is the problem in this sparql query? Also I want to work in protege 5.5 and not in mesh rdf web.

Comment: 1) I doubt that `owl:` is the correct prefix for your class, check your ontology for the full URI of your class `Consept` 2) even if it would be, then I consider this bad practice as the OWL namespace is a reserved vocabulary, and you would do some kind of hijacking here 3) is "Con**s**ept" the correct word? Or did you mean "Con**c**ept"